# Averaging daily varying column in excel vb

Tags: excel, vbscript

Every day I have to analyze two cols of numbers.

1. Cols differ each day.
2. Col 1 has no.'s from 1 to 5, eg. Day 1 there are 150 x 1's and 200 x 2's, etc. Day 2,  350 x 1's and 85 x 2's etc.
3. Col 2 has values between 1 and 99.

I need to count how many 1's there are to obtain a 1's average, 2's ave., etc. So far I have tried to write a vb program (excel 2010) - I have written the following:

```
Function Phil2()
ct = 0
For X = 2 To 10
If ax = 1 Then Let b15 = b15 + bx
ct = ct + 1
Next
End Function.
```

But I cannot get it to display. Can anyone help me?
I want the average of the 1's in cell b15.

Comment: Can you please reformat this question to show your data set. It's hard to get at what you are looking for exactly. If all you need is an average, I don't think you need to implement VBA, but until there is a clearer picture of what your ask is, it will be hard to interpret and ultimately, help.

Comment: Today a2 to a150 might be filled with 1's, a151 to a235 with 2's, etc. Tomorrow a2 to a340 might be filled with 1's, ... . Cells b2 onwards all have a % value. I want to, on a daily basis, have an average for all the 1's and the 2's, etc.. So we need to calculate the total for the 1's .., the no. of 1's and then the average. If possible ignoring the zero %'s.

Comment: got it. see answer below. No VBA needed.

Answer (score 0):

See the formula bar for what is in cell E1. If you don't have XL2007 or above, the formula becomes:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SUMIF($A$1:$B$10,D1,$B$1:$B$10)/COUNTIF($A$1:$B$10,D1)),"",SUMIF($A$1:$B$10,D1,$B$1:$B$10)/COUNTIF($A$1:$B$10,D1))
```

You could also make more "automated" by using [Dynamic Named Ranges](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm) for your ID (1,2,3..) and data (%) sets, that change each day.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Just two things:

Comment: What are you two things? Nothing after the `:`

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Just 2 things: 1. Blank spaces are counted. eg. if b3 is blank the formula still divides by 10. 2. I have quite a few columns, column a stays the same (1's and 2's etc) but columns C, D and so on also have %'s and I need to have averages for each of them. (It's for a dairy farm - Column B is % milk, C is weight of cow and so on). So the idea is to have the totals above each column - (Your d1 will go to a1, e1 will go to e1..  The values on your sheet (a1 to a10 will go down to a10 to a19). I only really need a count for 1, 2 and 3+ - ie. 3,4,5,6 ..can be lumped together).

Comment: okay, well, now you have changed the specifications, so if you fell my answer met your original specifications, please mark it as satisfactory. I can work out the new specs a little later, on, but I encourage you to look into the AverageIfs function, which can average on multiple criteria. For the ranges, just drag the formula across the columns.

Comment: Thanks Scott. The formula you gave is great - just the one thing - it counts a blank - some spaces may have blanks.

Comment: Do this, assuming cell references on my snapshot above =IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($B$1:$B$10,$A$1:$A$10,$D1,$B$1:$B$10,">0"),"")

Answer (score 0):

OK, It works fine - I modified your formula to:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(B$16:B$500,$A$16:$A$500,$A2,B$16:B$500,">0"),"")
```

and it works perfectly for values 1, and 2. So that's a great start. I placed the formula cells on top: so in a1 I typed cow no., in b1 %Milk, in c1 %weight, etc.. In a2 I typed 1, a3 2, a4 3 etc.. In b2 your formula etc.. My next challenge is to lump together all cow types 3 to 11. So next to cow type 1 we have a % for each category, same for cow type 2, etc.. But the 3rd row must have an average for all categories 3+. Raw data cow types are in a10 down, vals in b10, c10, etc.

Comment: If you are trying to ask a new question, please mark the answer on this question as satisfactory and open a new post with your new question. That way others can find the answer to this more easily, as well as your new question.